# Numerical way to find functions satisfying the following conditions

Tags: numerical-methods, roots

Given the following conditions;

\begin{align}
f[y_1(x)]f[y_2(x)] - \left\lbrace 1 - f[y_2(x)] \right\rbrace \omega(x) &= 0\\
f(0) &= 0\\
f(\infty) &= 1,
\end{align}
I'd like to find function $f$, which is continuous. The functions $y_1$, $y_2$ and $\omega$ are all known and continuous. $y_1$ and $y_2$ are also strictly monotonic.

Is there an approach to compute the function $f$ numerically?

Thank you.

Comment: Do $y_1$ and $y_2$ map $[0, \infty)$ to $[0, \infty)$?

Comment: $x \in [0, 1)$, so $y_1$ and $y_2$ map $[0, 1)$ to $[0, \infty)$, function $f$ is a statistical distribution. maybe it is necessary to define the function type, like e.g. normal distribution.

Comment: Do you have explicit formulas for $y_1, y_2, \omega$?

Comment: No, the functions $y_1$, $y_2$, and $\omega$ are obtained numerically.

Comment: The generic way may be to parametrize $f$  using a finite set of $K$ parameters then plug it into the equations at $K-2$ points $x_k, k = 1, \dots, K-2$ and solve the nonlinear system. The other option is to perform a fit on the whole $x \in [0, 1]$ interval

Comment: To be able to fit the function, I need to assume that it is of a specific type, if I understand correctly. Do I need to do that with the nonlinear set of equations?

Comment: Maybe you can do some plots for $y_1, y_2, \omega$ so I could make some experiments? Yes, you need to assume some a priori form of $f(y)$ for that.

Comment: No, sorry. $f$ is a CUMULATIVE distribution function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49836/discussion-between-daniel-and-uranix).